# How to access asp.net application faster for First request?

Tags: asp.net, performance, powershell, iis, web-farm

We are having approximately 100 virtual directories in server and all the 100 virtual directories will be pointing to single physical path. For every update, it is taking lot of time to access URL's for first request only. Is there any way to access the first request of Asp.net application faster or any explicit way to process the first request.

Comment: No. On the first request actually IIS executes your code and stores in cache (or somewhere) for later use. So, you won't be able to make it any faster.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way to build the cache files explicitly like precompiling the virtual directory? So that it will be faster I think.

Comment: Jon Tirjan's answer should help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with IIS 7.5, there is an extension available which was designed to address exactly what you're looking for.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization